# show loading image while the page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, domready

I want to show a `Loading` image when the page is not loaded yet. Before loading the page it shows a `blank white page` to the user. So, i want to remove the white blank space.

The page makes too many database hits, so it loads a bit slowly.

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535020/show-image-while-page-is-loading) post, but that doesn't work.

I've checked by adding `<![CDATA[` infront of the script, as it stated in the [blogpost](http://www.dzyngiri.com/show-loading-image-while-the-website-loads/#comment-14925).
That doesn't work.

Finally i've landed in Asking a Question, though it is a duplicate.

Here is my script finally.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
        $(window).load(function () {
            $("#divLoading").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

and in the body

```
<body style="background-color: white;">
    <div id='divLoading'>
        <div class="loading" align="center" id="divImageLoader">
            <img src="../../ItemSelectorImages/ajax-loader_bluish.gif" alt="Loading..."/>  Loading 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The CSS of loading is:

```
.loading
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding:20px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 99999;
    border-radius:5px;

}
```

What was wrong with my code ? Can someone point out or give working solution.

Cheers !!!

Karthik

Comment: is this a blank page or what the page loads after many database hits..?

Comment: another approach might be to load your page layout and text, then bring in the images with ajax calls.

Comment: make sure that loading div has 100% height of page!

Comment: There may be a problem with `load` event, as it's not always fully supported. You could use `ready`, although it is a little bit different.

Comment: @ghaxx onload event of window object is fully supported on all browser, problem comes for script/CSS or images

Comment: @DipeshParmar No BlockUI at all. Does BlockUI loads the images before DOM Ready.

Comment: guys, make sure you learned css before you take work. His loader just has no height. http://jsfiddle.net/PS43p/  working example

Comment: @AntoVinish Actually there are dropdown values and a huge stored proc that fetches the result on to the page. so, for a low speed internet it takes much time. And hence the blank screen is being shown. After the data is loaded, it displays the content as expected

Comment: @A. Wolff: You may be right, but there's still a note about `load` on http://api.jquery.com/load-event/. So maybe this is connected with the problem?

Comment: If the delay is because of database hits then the server will not send any response to browser so you have to show a temporary loading page and use Ajax calls to get finished all the database works and after the response redirect to the original page

Comment: @GenaLondon Thanks Gena for fiddle. I just copied the css in the fiddle to the css files.I've set the height of the `divLoading` to 100%,but still doesn't work.

Comment: @ghaxx because you are wrapping inside onload handler, so code is executed once page is loaded and so it's too late to fire onload event. Ready event (jquery) is particular, it is a pseudo event which will fired even the DOM is already ready, using a promise resolved manually. Note that once fired, ready handlers are unbound, you cannot later trigger it again manually. Hope what i said makes sense

Comment: @ghaxx concerning note, this is just due to the fact than onload event doesn't propagate/bubble throught the DOM, making delegation unefficient. That's said, the real problem with onload event is regarding images and CSS external files as i'm aware of.

Comment: @AntoVinish though there are database hits, the page has loading div right after the body, then why does it wont show up ? Also the database calls will be in the Page_Load() in code behind file

Comment: @A. Wolff: Makes sense. Just to clarify: your answer is to my question from previous comment, which I edited. It was about `load` and `ready` on jsfiddle.

Comment: OP, if ajax requests are done during page loading, you should use global ajax event as $.ajaxStop() to remove loading img the first time ajaxStop is fired. Could be a solution i think

Comment: @A.Wolff But there are no ajax call is being made for the first time when the page loads. It just shows a blank page. After the page is loaded ajax call were made and i'm showing the same image as a loading image and it works perfect. But when the page is loaded for the very first time it should show the loading image as Gena London has mentioned in her fiddle

Comment: @karthik I'm sorry, i read before an other question regarding ajax and have blend both questions, my apologies...

Comment: @A.Wolff I've got this working. I've posted as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution to this question.

The problem is not with the height of the div element nor the Images/CSS problem.

The problem is with another `script` that is executed right after the window load completes, the script includes the DOM ready and remaining javascript function(s).

I've removed the next script that is executed after the window.load and placed after end of the body tag.

```
<body style="background-color: white;">
    <div id='divLoading'>
        <div class="loading" align="center" id="divImageLoader">
            <img src="../../ItemSelectorImages/ajax-loader_bluish.gif" alt="Loading..."/>  Loading 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
//The following second script is placed here so as to load after the body load is complete.
<script>
       includes DOM Ready, and some javascript functions to be called.
</script>
```

**Assumption:** I think after the `$(window).load(function () {` script is done, there should not be any other scripts further running.

Thanks to all the guys who commented.

If my assumption is wrong, please mention what the real problem that stopped the `loading` image to show up.